# Protractor: Expected [ true, true ] to be true

Tags: node.js, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I'm running a test that checks if a div contains certain text. If it contains this text, I then want to see if a link further down the page contains the same text.
I.e a user will have a EUR and USD balance  displayed at the header of the page, then further down the page there will be a tab that contains a link called "EUR" and another tab contains a link with the text "USD".

When I run my script I get the error:

```
Expected [ true, true ] to be true.
```

This is my code from the page object file

```js
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.className("currencies")), 4000));
    var checkBalance = element(by.className("currencies"));
      checkBalance.getText().then(function (text) {
           if(text.indexOf("EUR") >-1 && text.indexOf("GBP") >-1){
        //check if currencies div contains "EUR" and "GBP"
            expect(element.all(by.linkText("EUR" && "GBP")).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
   //check if link with text "EUR" and link with "GBP" is displayed
      }
```

Comment: Try using `.toBeTruthy();` if you have more then one element that matches?

Comment: Thanks, I had actually used .toBeTruthy() before and had to switch toBeTrue() and had forgotten about it in the meantime. That has helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

**Be aware of using `.toBeTruthy()`, see [this post](https://vincenttunru.com/toBeTruthy-vs-toBe-true/)**.

The reason why you get `Expected [ true, true ] to be true.` is because you use `element.all(by.linkText("EUR" && "GBP")).isDisplayed()`, this will return an array with the `.isDisplayed()` result of each `element` (because you are using `.all`).

**What you know did is creating a false positive.** You can test this by changing the `expect(element.all(by.linkText("EUR" && "GBP")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();` to `expect(element.all(by.linkText("Bar" && "Foo")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();` Both will succeed.

If you look at BDD and TDD, it's better to first create a failing testcase, and then make the testcase work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried using `toBe(true);` in my original post but that wasn't working for me. What is BDD and TDD? I'm not really sure how to proceed

Comment: if you want to use `toBe();` then use `toBe([true, true]);` because you need to compare an array with an array. BDD = Behaviour Driven Development, TDD = Test Driven Development.

Did you also try the expect with non existing link texts?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it still passed when I changed the values to "bar" and "foo". `toBe([true, true)];` has helped me out a lot, thanks. My issue now is that if I go `expect(element.all(by.linkText("EUR" && "foo")).isDisplayed()).toBe([true, true]);` it will pass as it is detecting "EUR" as being present and it doesn't seem to care about "foo". Any idea how I change this line of code so that it will check if both "EUR" and "GBP" is present? It will fail if I go `expect(element.all(by.linkText("bar" && "foo")).isDisplayed()).toBe([true, true]);` so It is working partially correct

Comment: Create 2 expectations. `by.linkText()` accepts a string, `"EUR" && "GBP"` will result in "GBD" . If you do this  `expect(element.(by.linkText("EUR")).isDisplayed()).toBe(true)` and `expect(element.(by.linkText("GBP")).isDisplayed()).toBe(true)`

Comment: Back again! The problem with me using `expect(element.(by.linkText("EUR"))` is that there are multiple links with the same name and I get  `more than one element found for locator By(link text, EUR) the first result will be used` If i use `element.all` I get my original error

Comment: Narrow it down to the correct element. You can use a "scope" in which it is living like `element(by.css(".parent")).element(by.linkText("EUR"))`